# What is the first parameter in Parse.User.signUp()?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for the database of my app and for my signup view, I'm trying to reduce the number of lines in my code.

```
user.set("username",$scope.user.email);
user.set("email",$scope.user.email);
user.set("password",$scope.user.password);
    user.signUp(null,
        { success: function(user) { 
            $ionicLoading.hide(); 
            $scope.state.success = true;
        }, error: function(user, error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            if (error.code == 125) { $scope.error.message = "Please specify a valid email address"; }
            else if (error.code == 202) { $scope.error.message = "The email address is already registered"; }
            else { $scope.error.message = error.message; }
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

My question is this: what is the first parameter supposed to be? On Parse.com, it does not use any examples where the first parameter is null (that I have seen). And I cannot find any docs that explain the `.signUp()` method with any detail.

My instinct tells me that this the parameter expects user data in a JSON format. But I don't know for sure.

**EDIT**: Solution:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.signUp({ 
    "username": $scope.user.email,
    "email": $scope.user.email, 
    "password": $scope.user.password 
}, { 
    success: function(user) 
    {   $ionicLoading.hide(); 
        $scope.state.success = true;
    }, 
    error: function(user, error) 
    {   $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (error.code == 125) { $scope.error.message = "Please specify a valid email address"; }
        else if (error.code == 202) { $scope.error.message = "The email address is already registered"; }
        else { $scope.error.message = error.message; }
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Parse SDK [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html#signUp):

```
signUp(attrs, options)
```

`attrs` are extra attributes to add to the user, or `null`.